# Where translated servlet of jsp got stored

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, weblogic9.x

As we know, when the jsp got complied it will get converted to servet.

I have installed weblogic server 9.2, and i deployed a struts project which has jsp files.
And in the browser i am able to see the application.

Now I want to see the servelt file of jsp which I ran.

Can anybody please tel me where I can find it 
or do i need to do some configurations for this because I searched whole weblogic directory there is no java file with the jsp file name.

Answer (score 8):

If WebLogic is compiling JSP (i.e. if you are not precompiling them), they should be located under `domain_name/servers/server-name-1/tmp/_WL_user`.

#### See also

- [Using JSP Precompilation in WebLogic](http://m-button.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-jsp-precompilation-in-weblogic.html)

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this today and found another option. If you deploy your application via eclipse (and not via EAR file using the weblogic console) the compiled JSPs will be in `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp<some digit>\<domain name>\work\<app name>\jsp_servlet`.

Answer (score 2):

For Weblogic 10.3.6, the folder  is this.

> C:\oracle\MIDDLEWARE\user_projects\domains\APPNAME\servers\myserver\tmp_WL_user_appsdir_APPNAME_dir\\jsp_servlet_jsp_content

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the `<working-dir></working-dir>` section in the `weblogic.xml` file to check for the location of `jsp_servlets` folder where the `.java` and `.class` files can be found.

You can trick the weblogic into recompiling the jsp files by deleting the existing ones, and try and access the jsp page from browser (in case lazy initialization is being followed).